# NoSuchMethodError with YouTube API in Java

Tags: java, youtube-api

I am writing a code in Java to upload videos to youtube from mu application.

**My code is :**

```
package com.youtube.video;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaCategory;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaDescription;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaKeywords;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaTitle;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.FormUploadToken;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YouTubeMediaGroup;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YouTubeNamespace;
import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

public class YouTubeController {

    public static YouTubeService service;

    public void init() {
      if (service == null) {
        service = new YouTubeService("mail@gmail.com", "A...A");
        String username = "mail@gmail.com";
        String password = "xxxxxxxxx";

        try {
          service.setUserCredentials(username, password);
        } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
          ae.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

    static String token;
    static String formUrl;
    public static void setFormDetails() throws IOException {
      VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();
      YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();

      String videoTitle = "this is a title";

      mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME, "Autos"));
      mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());
      mg.setPrivate(false);
      mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
      mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("");
      mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent(videoTitle);
      mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
      mg.getDescription().setPlainTextContent(videoTitle);

      URL uploadUrl = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken");

      try {
        FormUploadToken fut = service.getFormUploadToken(uploadUrl, newEntry);
        token = fut.getToken();
        System.out.println(">>>>>"+token);
        formUrl = fut.getUrl();
      } catch (ServiceException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) throws IOException {
        YouTubeController yc = new YouTubeController();
        yc.init();
        yc.setFormDetails();
    }
}
```

I have the following jars in lib folder :

gdata-client-1.0.jar
gdata-youtube-2.0.jar
gdata-core-1.0.jar
gdata-media-1.0.jar
google-collect-1.0.jar
guava-13.0.1.jar
mail.jar
activation.jar

But while running this piece of code, **it is giving me the following error** :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableTypes(AltFormat.java:399)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableXmlTypes(AltFormat.java:387)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat.<clinit>(AltFormat.java:49)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:558)
    at com.zeta.video.YouTubeController.init(YouTubeController.java:23)
    at com.zeta.video.YouTubeController.main(YouTubeController.java:66)
```

I tried all solutions over net, and all of them points out that this error is because i am missing some JAR files. But i am having all the JARs. Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: How are you building this project?

Comment: What are you using to build this code?

Comment: I am referring to what editor/build platform you are using. It sounds as though you are not correctly referencing the jar files you mention in the lib folder. Are you using Eclipse? The command line? Netbeans? IntelliJ?

Comment: Oops, sorry for lame answer. I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you are referencing both **google-collections** and **guava**. Since **guava** is a superset of **google-collections** you actually only need to reference **guava**. Remove the reference to **google-collections** and you should find the problem is resolved.